# Can't connect to Redis instance: Redis error: NOAUTH (undefined)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, socket.io

`SocketIO` adapter is configured this way, all variables are set up and checked:

```js
const pub = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_HOST, { auth_pass: REDIS_PASSWORD });
const sub = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_HOST, { auth_pass: REDIS_PASSWORD });
io.adapter(redisAdapter({ pubClient: pub, subClient: sub }));
```

`redis.conf` used in Redis container looks this way:

```
requirepass mypassword2023
```

The config file gets copied to the container without problems:

```yaml
[...]
    volumes:
      - ./redis:/usr/local/etc/redis/
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
[...]
```

I'm able to get into running Redis container and authenticate myself:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH mypassword2023
OK
```

But when I try to reach the Redis instance from my backend, I get the `NOAUTH` error. It means, the backend indeed gets to the Redis instance, but it also gives incorrect password and can't operate further.

Any hints on how to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are using node-redis here (https://github.com/redis/node-redis/).

When connecting and providing a hostname, port and password you have two options.  First you could use the config object like this:

```
const myClient = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    port: REDIS_PORT, 
    host: REDIS_HOST
  },
  password: REDIS_PASSWORD 
);
```

My personal preference is to use a single secret for an entire Redis URL formatted connection (https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/redis).  Here's an example using the secrets setup that you have in your code:

```
const myClient = redis.createClient({
  url: `redis://default:${REDIS_PASSWORD}@${REDIS_HOST}:${REDIS_PORT}`
});
```

Where `default` is the user name you'll use if you are using the server wide `requirepass` password like you are.

Note that node-redis 4 returns a connection in `myClient` but you'll want to connect it to the Redis server before using it:

```
await redisClient.connect();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case `socket.io-redis` is in use to handle Redis communication. However, thanks for pointing out there are other options available: maybe I'll decide to switch to using something more configurable.